# Assigning the points that a client of origin passes to a destination with SQL of Carto

Tags: carto

At the point of destination, can I choose how many kilometers of radius to calculate the points a customer goes through?

I know I have to use the function `cdb_route_point_to_point`.

For example, I have these two tables:

Table 1 has the points of origin and table 2 the points of destination.

Imagine that for Origin A it goes to destination T1, and on the route it goes through points T2 and T3.

With Carto, how do I assign the points that go through the route? The result would be a table as the last image

[image: tables]
[image: FINAL TABLE description here]

route:

[image: route]

Comment: Can you please elaborate more your use case? I understand you want to use the Data Services API, is the documentation of the function not enough? Are you missing something there?

Comment: Yes, I think I should use the Data Services API.
I'm doing tests.
I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the routing function that allows you to specify waypoints, more details [here](https://carto.com/developers/data-services-api/reference/#cdb_route_with_waypointswaypoints-geometrypoint-mode-text-options-text-units-text). You'll need to collect your points into an array using a `group by` statement so you have an ordered list per route.